# Ошибка в работе с базой данных в запросе с JOIN

Tags: mysql, laravel

Делаю выборку из БД. Часть кода, при выполнении которого возникает ошибка:

```
if (count($rgColl) > 0) {
    $this->projects->join('object_collection', function($join) use($rgColl) {
        $join->on('object_collection.object_id', '=', 'objects.id');
        if (count($rgColl) == 1) {
            $join->where('object_collection.collection_id', '=', $rgColl[0]);
        } else {
            $join->whereIn('object_collection.collection_id', $rgColl);
        }
    });
    $this->select[] = 'object_collection.object_id';
    $this->select[] = 'object_collection.collection_id';
    $this->group[]  = 'object_collection.object_id';
}
```

Если в `$rgColl` 1 элемент, то результат возвращается нормально.
Если выполняется конструкция `$join->whereIn('object_collection.collection_id', $rgColl);`, то выдает ошибку:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? where `objects`.`category_id` = ? group by `object_parameters_size`.`object_id' at line 1

Беру код запроса, сгенерированный Laravel v5, и просто выполняю его в MySQL Workbench - данные возвращаются.

Полный запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT 
    `objects`.`id`,
    `objects`.`ord`,
    `objects`.`title`,
    `objects`.`art`,
    `objects`.`code`,
    `object_parameters_size`.`object_id`,
    `object_parameters_size`.`parameter_id`,
    `object_parameters_size`.`valint`,
    `object_collection`.`object_id`,
    `object_collection`.`collection_id`
FROM 
  `objects`
  INNER JOIN `object_parameters` AS `object_parameters_size` ON `object_parameters_size`.`object_id` = `objects`.`id`
    AND `object_parameters_size`.`parameter_id` = 1
    AND `object_parameters_size`.`valint` > 0
    AND `object_parameters_size`.`valint` < 500
  INNER JOIN `object_collection` ON `object_collection`.`object_id` = `objects`.`id`
        AND `object_collection`.`collection_id` IN (38,15,39,40,41)
WHERE
    `objects`.`category_id` = 1
GROUP BY `object_parameters_size`.`object_id` , `object_collection`.`object_id`
ORDER BY `objects`.`ord` ASC
```

Аномалия какая-то получается.

Answer (score 1):

Элементарное гугление:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4412
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913776/laravel-4-add-wherein-clause-to-a-join-condition

Не возможно сделать join->whereIn()